# How to remove characters after the Nth matching character from a string in powershell

Tags: powershell

How do i remove all the characters after the nth number of a matching character in powershell?

Example:
\1CF\0101\FIXED\PIPING\0101-000\0101-000-000\Crkg_O_S_I\1997_O_S_I

I want to remove all the characters after the 7th "\" so the output would be
\1CF\0101\FIXED\PIPING\0101-000\0101-000-000 or 
\1CF\0101\FIXED\PIPING\0101-000\0101-000-000\
Doesn't matter which of the output is

Comment: This helped a lot. Thanks. I was also able to apply this in an array

Get-Content "from.txt" | foreach { ($_.Split("\",8) | select -index 1,2,3,4,5,6) -join "\" } | out-file "test2output.csv"

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - put this as the answer. Nice, easy and quick response. +1!

Comment: @RossLyons ok, it's an answer :)

Comment: Is the delimiter an arbitrary character, or do you have path strings (meaning the delimiter is a backslash or forward slash)? In case of the latter you could simply use `Split-Path -Parent`.

Answer (score 2):

[moving this from my comment] I think splitting the string into parts based on backslashes, then taking the first 7 parts and ignoring the rest, and joining those 7 back up with new backslashes is quite a short, sensible approach:

```
$string.split('\')[0..6] -join '\'
```

Other approaches would be to repeatedly do `$index = $string.IndexOf('\', $index + 1)` until it had found the location of the 7th and then use `$string.SubString()`. For a small saving of memory (no array created to hold the split pieces), this is likely not worth it.